# MongoDB Data directory /data/db not found

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04, lts

When I try to run Mongod in terminal I got this message :

```
2015-05-14T17:33:04.554+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2015-05-14T17:33:04.554+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

and running mongo command  :

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
2015-05-14T17:34:26.679+0700 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-05-14T17:34:26.681+0700 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

I Have tried to change permision in /var/lib/mongodb and /var/log/mongodb, but still doesnt work, and I tried to uninstall and install mongodb again, but still the same problem exist.
Anyone could help? Thanks

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Answer (score 132, accepted):

MongoDB needs data directory to store data.
Default path is `/data/db`

When you start MongoDB engine, it searches this directory which  is missing in your case. Solution is create this directory and assign `rwx` permission to user.

If you want to change the path of your data directory then you should specify it while starting mongod server like,

```
mongod --dbpath /data/<path> --port <port no>
```

This should help you start your mongod server with custom path and port.

Comment: where should I create thid directory? in root dir ?

Comment: In "/"  dir. I have provided absolute path "/data/db" or "/data/mydir" for custom path.

Comment: Thanks It work after a while when creating the directory and restart the mongoDB

Comment: I'd go for creating /data/db folders in the Root folder. 

Make sure that the user that starts the deamon mongod has permissions to those folders.
Then you just have to run:
--> mongod
 and it should work

Comment: try: `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: Why doesn't mongo do this for you when installing? Feels like a unfinished installation.

Comment: Even that isn't working for me. Installed it via `sudo npm install mongodb`.

Comment: Starting mongo as a service worked for me. I wonder if it would be possible for them to make mongod process check  /etc/mongod.conf file instead of going to /data/db in the future.

Comment: try running the mongo DB via brew services, `brew services start mongodb`

Comment: @GujaratSantana this(https://fantinel.dev/mongodb-error-datadb-on-linux/) page has a more detailed explanation on what to do when /data/db is missing. Worked for me