# Connection to MongoDB fails

Tags: mongodb

I tried to connect to a local MongoDB instance, but it failed with error message `Failed to connect`.

I have run the commands shown in the below screenshots. The error message is shown there, too.

My folder structure is:

- D:/mongodb/bin
- D:/mongodb/data/db
- D:/mongodb/log

I am using 32-bit Windows7.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235200/mongodb-data-directory-data-db-not-found/30235233#30235233

Comment: Added some formatting to the question, slightly improved case and removed "thanks".

Answer (score 1):

Your data directory doesn't exist where MongoDB is expecting it to be.

For simplicity you can create `D:/data/db`, which is the default location and where `mongod` is looking at the moment, and use this as your data directory.

Alternatively if you want to use `D:/mongodb/data/db` as the data directory you'll need to [specify the dbPath](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-data-directory) when starting `mongod`

```
mongod --dbpath D:/mongodb/data/db
```

This can also be done in a [configuration file](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath).