# Installing BigchainDB with MongoDB bug

Tags: mongodb, blockchain

I tried to install BigchainDB with MongoDB by command:

`mongod --replSet=bigchain-rs` but it doesn't work the error message is :

```
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=29536 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=chebbi-X556UV
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-21T15:45:19.256+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { replication: { replSet: "bigchain-rs" } }
2017-02-21T15:45:19.292+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2017-02-21T15:45:19.292+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-02-21T15:45:19.292+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-02-21T15:45:19.292+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-02-21T15:45:19.292+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the directory `/data/db` does not exist. Take a look to this question, it might help you solving your problem:

- [MongoDB Data directory /data/db not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235200/mongodb-data-directory-data-db-not-found)